# How to sort results with $lookup and $unwind in aggregate mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to sort the results order by `createdAt` field in `$lookup` pipeline but the output is incorrect, I have found my problem and found that `$sort` will be not worked with `$unwind`, but in my case I need to use $unwind for $lookup. How I can resolve this issue?
I am looking forward to receiving helps.

My code:

```
 db.posts.collection.aggregate([

    ...,
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'images', // join to images model 
            localField: 'images',
            foreignField: '_id',
            pipeline: [
               {
                  $sort: {
                      createdAt: -1, // sort working incorrectly
                  },
               },
            ],
            as: 'images',
        },
    },

    {
        $unwind: {
            path: '$images',
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
    },

 ])
```

Comment: You can sort after the  `$unwind`

Comment: So, you `"$unwind"` `"images"` before the `"$lookup"`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it not works if i am using $addToSet in $group, but will works if I replace $addToSet by $push

Comment: @nimrodserok  $sort will not worked if I am using $addToSet in $group

Comment: I don't see any `$group` here. Please edit your question to include sample documents, requested output from them and your main logic

Answer (score 0):

Sort in a pipeline will short your data which is inside a images field, it wan't sort entire data, you can use sort option outside like this.

```
        db.posts.collection.aggregate([

        ...,
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'images', // join to images model 
                localField: 'images',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'images',
            },
        },
        {
            $unwind: {
                path: '$images',
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
            },
        },
        {
            $sort:{"images.createdAt":-1}
        }

    ])
```